# Python selenium select text element by style

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

On this page 'https://www.nj.gov/health/cd/topics/covid2019_dashboard.shtml', I try to get the number of New Jersey Positives (upper right of the dashboard).

```
    positiveCount = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//text[@style='stroke-width: 2; font-size: 160px; line-height: normal;']")
    print len(positiveCount)
```

it always show 0.

What did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The data is wrapped in iframe so you have to switch to the iframe first and then get the details.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(0)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('text').text
```

Result:

'6,876'

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please find solution

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
url = 'https://www.nj.gov/health/cd/topics/covid2019_dashboard.shtml'
driver.get(url)
driver.maximize_window()

iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'iframe')))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

svg = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
     EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'text')))
print svg.text
```